# implement filter functionality using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I wanna implement filter functionality for my web table. Based on the dropdown list selection the table has to show respective data.  For example : Drop down list contains two data: Yes , NO.

If user select "Yes" then It should display the following table:

S.NO ||  Name  || Member
0101  ||  Pieter Josh || Yes

If user selecting "No" from drop down It should display as below:

S.NO ||  Name  || Member
0101  || Debiee || No

The Yes, and NO should be mapped with Member column. If the values are present It should display corresponding row in table.

Please help me to implement this.

Since the web table is dynamic it may contains 100 yes or NO. Based on the drop down list, It should return the proper rows in table.

Hopefully expecting some inputs from somebody in this group.

Comment: so where problem? _Since the web table is dynamic_ just filter data before render

Comment: Also,  I don't have id or class attribute in tr, td tags. Because It's created dynamically. But, the table can have id attribute .

Comment: how you generate table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery will solve it easier than Javascript.

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $.each($('table tr td:nth-child(5)'), function(index, value) {
    if ($('select').val() == 'all') {
      $(value).closest('tr').show();
    } else if ($(value).text().toLowerCase().trim() ==
      $('select').val().toLowerCase().trim()) {
      $(value).closest('tr').show();
    } else {
      $(value).closest('tr').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<br />
<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Yes/No</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>80</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this help.